# How to split a datafile into multiple parts along with comments in each splitted files?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a datafile like this:

```
# coating file for detector A/R
# column 1 is the angle of incidence (degrees)
# column 2 is the wavelength (microns)
# column 3 is the transmission probability
# column 4 is the reflection probability
      14.2000     0.531000    0.0618000     0.938200
      14.2000     0.532000    0.0790500     0.920950
      14.2000     0.533000    0.0998900     0.900110
# it has lots of other lines
# datafile can be obtained from pastebin
```

The link to input datafile is:
http://pastebin.com/NaNbEm3E

I like to create 20 files from this input such that each files have the comments line.

That is :

```
#out1.txt
#comments
   first part of one-twentieth data

# out2.txt
# given comments
   second part of one-twentieth data

# and so on upto out20.txt
```

How can we do so in python?

My intitial attempt is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Author    : Bhishan Poudel
# Date      : May 23, 2016


# Imports
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read in comments from the file
infile = 'filecopy_multiple.txt'
outfile = 'comments.txt'
comments = []
with open(infile, 'r') as fi, open (outfile, 'a') as fo:
    for line in fi.readlines():
        if line.startswith('#'):
            comments.append(line)
            print(line)
            fo.write(line)


#==============================================================================
# read in a file
#
infile = infile
colnames = ['angle', 'wave','trans','refl']
print('{} {} {} {}'.format('\nreading file : ', infile, '','' ))
df = pd.read_csv(infile,sep='\s+', header = None,skiprows = 0,
                 comment='#',names=colnames,usecols=(0,1,2,3))
print('{} {} {} {}'.format('length of df : ', len(df),'',''))


# write 20 files
df = df
nfiles = 20
nrows = int(len(df)/nfiles)
groups = df.groupby(   np.arange(len(df.index)) / nrows   )
for (frameno, frame) in groups:
    frame.to_csv("output_%s.csv" % frameno,index=None, header=None,sep='\t')
```

Till now I have twenty splitted files. I just want to copy the comments lines to each of the files. But the question is: `how to do so?`

There should be some easier method than creating another 20 output files with comments only and appending twenty_splitted_files to them.

Some useful links are following:
[How to split a dataframe column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034361/how-to-split-a-dataframe-column-into-multiple-columns)
[How to split a DataFrame column in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733587/how-to-split-a-dataframe-column-in-python)
[Split a large pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315737/split-a-large-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: It's not quite clear why do you need pandas/data frames in this case...  Do you want to keep existing file format or do you want to save splited files as normal CSV or HDF5 files?

Comment: @MaxU  i want to save splitted files as normal CSV files so that each twenty output files have the same header comments as that of input file.

Comment: Does your original CSV file fit into RAM or do you have to read it line-by-line?

Comment: @MaxU my original CSV fits into RAM, its not very large file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** optimized code

```
fn = r'D:\download\input.txt'

with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

comments_lines = 0
for line in data:
    if line.strip().startswith('#'):
        comments_lines += 1
    else:
        break

nfiles = 20
chunk_size = (len(data)-comments_lines)//nfiles

for i in range(nfiles):
    with open('d:/temp/output_{:02d}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as f:
        f.write(''.join(data[:comments_lines] + data[comments_lines+i*chunk_size:comments_lines+(i+1)*chunk_size]))
        if i == nfiles - 1 and len(data) > comments_lines+(i+1)*chunk_size:
            f.write(''.join(data[comments_lines+(i+1)*chunk_size:]))
```

**Original answer:**

```
comments = []
data = []

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

i = 0
for line in data:
        if line.strip().startswith('#'):
            comments.append(line)
            i += 1
        else:
            break

data[:] = data[i:]

i=0
for x in range(0, len(data), len(data)//20):
    with open('output_{:02d}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as f:
        f.write(''.join(comments + data[x:x+20]))
        i += 1
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "split_file_with_comments.py", line 25, in <module>
    data = [line] + f.readlines()
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Comment: @MaxU_ I am using macos 10.9 and this code shows same error for python2 and python3, I just removed D:download\  and d:/temp/ names. python3 again shows VALUE_ERROR

Comment: @BhishanPoudel, i've updated my answer - please check

Comment: @MaxU_  Now it works for both python2 and python3 for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BhishanPoudel, i've optimized the code a little bit, so it'll loop much less now - it should work much faster

Comment: @MaxU_ Small problem: there are 21 files (00 to 20), even though i changed 20 to 19 in your code.

Comment: @BhishanPoudel, it should be fixed now - please check

Comment: @MaxU_sir_ Now it is perfect, total data lines = 166, first 19 files have 19*8=152 lines, and last file = 14 lines, total 152+14=166, its perfect!

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do it

```
# Store comments in this to use for all files
comments = []

# Create a new sub list for each of the 20 files
data = []
for _ in range(20):
    data.append([])

# Track line number
index = 0

# open input file
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fi:
    # fetch all lines at once so I can count them.
    lines = fi.readlines()

    # Loop to gather initial comments
    line = lines[index]
    while line.split()[0] == '#':
        comments.append(line)
        index += 1
        line = lines[index]

    # Calculate how many lines of data
    numdata = len(lines) - len(comments)

    for i in range(index, len(lines)):
        # Calculate which of the 20 files I'm working with
        filenum = (i - index) * 20 / numdata
        # Append line to appropriately tracked sub list
        data[filenum].append(lines[i])

for i in range(1, len(data) + 1):
    # Open output file
    with open('output{}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as fo:
        # Write comments
        for c in comments:
            fo.write(c)
        # Write data
        for line in data[i-1]:
            fo.write(line)
```

Comment: @piRSquared_ Thanks a lot.